# Using regular expression to match specific data

Tags: python, regex

Using regular expressions with Python, attempting to parse through the data below.

The Data **thing1=**

```
href="quote.ashx?t=JBL&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">4.47B</a>, <a 
t=JBL&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">18.35</a>, <a class="screener-link" 
style="color:#008800;">24.15</span></a>, <a class="screener-link" 
style="color:#008800;">11.96%</span></a>, <a class="screener-link" 
href="quote.ashx?t=JBL&amp;ty=c&amp;p=d&amp;b=1">16,932,307</a>
```

The Regular Expression

```
pattern = "\b\d+(?:\.\d+)"
match = re.findall(pattern,thing1)
print(match)
```

That expression matches all of the decimal numbers [Here](https://regex101.com/r/fF8ekE/5)!

The result I am getting is as expected...

```
['4.47', '18.35', '24.15', '11.96']
```

But I just want the 24.15. Is there any patters matching in the data that would yield this result?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use this web site to experiment with regular expressions in real time: https://regex101.com/. How is 24.15 different from 18.35?

Comment: From a pattern matching perspective, I think the difference would be the text before the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML and regex are not good friends, I highly encourage you to use an HTML parser instead.

If you insist to use regex, you should be more specific in choosing the relevant pattern. Since there's nothing special about the digits you want to extract (they both appear to have the same pattern - before and after), you can try something like:

```
specific_text(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

where `specific_text` can be `<span style=\"color.*?>` in your example (here you'll get two results, the first one is what you're looking for).